# Zend Framework 2 - Translate Standard Form Validation and Error messages

Tags: php, validation, zend-form, zend-framework2, zend-translate

I'm writing a complete German application and therefore need to set basically everything to German.

My question: What is the best and easiest way to set for example the form validation to German?

I found [this page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.i18n.html) but couldn't figure out how to get this code working:

```
Zend_Validate_Abstract::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
```

Could anyone give me some advice how to use this?

**Edit:**

Thanks to @Gordon I put the following into my Application/Module.php:

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class Module
{
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    ...

     $translator = new Translator();
     $translator->addTranslationFile(
      'phpArray',
      'resources/languages/de.php',
      'default',
      'de_DE'
     );
         AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
    ...
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Alright, this is odd. When I set `de_DE` I get the message that the de.php file couldn't be opened - which is true because "de" is a folder containing two other PHP files.

> Could not open file resources/languages/de.php for reading

Altering the path to the folder or to any existing file within it doesnt help...

When I change the "de_DE" to "de" or "de_de" then nothing happens. No error and English validation errors. Any clues?

Comment: Your very question is answered in the [reference guide about `Zend_Validate` in the chapter about "Using pre-translated validation messages"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.messages.html). The code snippet looks wrong though (should probably be a different filename and locale). In any case, try that and then update your question if it doesn't work. Make sure to include any error messages-

Comment: Try with 'resources/languages/de' or 'resources/languages/de/Zend_Validate.php'

Comment: thanks, needed to add the full path to the `addTranslationFile` fct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found with help of @Gordon the answer!

I put the following into my Application/Module.php:

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class Module
{
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    ...

     $translator = new Translator();
     $translator->addTranslationFile(
      'phpArray',
      'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/Zend_Validate.php',
      'default',
      'de_DE'
     );
     AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
    ...
}
```

Then you need to enable php5-intl. Go to php.ini and enable `extension=php_intl.dll`.

Finally I needed to add the full path (starting with vendor) in the funciton provided by Gordon and the docs.

Comment: Please not the \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator introduced in Zend 2.2 (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.html)

Comment: The later versions of Zend FW must have translators with specific interfaces. See my comment below.

Answer (score 8):

for me it works with

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $translator=$e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
    $translator->addTranslationFile(
        'phpArray',
        './vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/it/Zend_Validate.php'

    );
    AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
   // \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($application);
}
```

'./vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/langfolderyouwant/Zend_Validate.php'

Comment: When using zend2.3 this seems like the desired way of doing it. The I18n translator got somewhat replaced by the Service MvcTranslator which implements a translator interface etc.

Answer (score 4):

The later versions of Zend FW must have translators with specific interfaces.

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        //...

        $translator = new Translator();
        $translator->addTranslationFile(
            'phpArray',
            'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/Zend_Validate.php',
            'default',
            'de_DE'
        );
        AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
        //...
    }
}
```

would become:

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
    //...

        $translator = new Translator();
        $translator->addTranslationFile(
            'phpArray',
            'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/Zend_Validate.php',
            'default',
            'de_DE'
        );
        AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator(
            new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator($translator)
        );
        //...
    }
}
```

Note the `new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator($translator)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pile code into onBootstrap and you only need just one language, you can use the configuration file:

```
'translator' => array (
    'locale' => 'ru',
    'translation_files' => [
        [
            'type' => 'phparray',
            'filename' => 'path/to/ru/directory/Zend_Validate.php'
        ]
    ],
),
```

Put it into you `module.config.php`

Answer (score 1):

For newest zf2 Version (2.5.0) you have to change the path to Zend_Validate.php to `./vendor/zendframework/zend-i18n-resources/languages/de/Zend_Validate.php`.

```
$translator->addTranslationFile(
    'phpArray',
    './vendor/zendframework/zend-i18n-resources/languages/de/Zend_Validate.php',
    'default',
    'de_DE'
);
```