# ZF2 Use non-en default locale for default Validator messages

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm fighting with ZF2 to force one specific validation messages translation for any incoming browser locale.
So I just want ZF2 to always use it's own provided translations of error messages to russian, this file:
`\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\resources\languages\ru\Zend_Validate.php`

I've tried creating Translator and setting it as Default at `onBootstrap`:

```
$translator = new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator();
$translator->addTranslationFile(
    'phpArray',
    'vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/ru/Zend_Validate.php',
    'default',
    'ru_RU'
);
AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

As this topic suggests - [Zend Framework 2 - Translate Standard Form Validation and Error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949240/zend-framework-2-translate-standard-form-validation-and-error-messages) but no effect!

I've tried forcing Locale at module config with the same no results:

```
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'ru_RU'
),
```

I'm not sure, maybe something is wrong with translation file URL? Cause when I try Z-Dumb the translator, it claims having 1 file registered by 0 messages.

Anyway, what is the easiest way to force default validator translation to always be russian?

Big thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you mention is `\resources\languages\ru\Zend_Validate.php` but the path in your config is `\resources\languages\Zend_Validate.php`. Mind the difference of the folder `ru`.

I would expect this already makes quite a difference. If not, can you try to force the locale with this added in your onBootstrap():

```
Locale::setDefault('ru_RU');
```

Comment: Yay! Sorry, I copy pasted code with invalid path (corrected the question). Thanks Jurian - the add of `\Locale::setDefault('ru_RU');` finally made it working!