# zf2 - pre-translated validation messages doesn't work for me

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework2, message

I've read and studied these links without result :

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.messages.html

[ZF2 Use non-en default locale for default Validator messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18150506/zf2-use-non-en-default-locale-for-default-validator-messages)

So, here is my code. I've just started from ZendSkeletonApplication.

Here is onBootstrap() in Class Module :

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);


    \Locale ::setDefault('fr_FR');

    $translator = new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator();
    $translator->addTranslationFile(
            'phpArray',
            'resources/languages/fr/Zend_Validate.php',
            __NAMESPACE__,
             'fr_FR'
    );
    \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
}
```

Here is a part of module.config.php :

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'fr_FR',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

And all validation messages are in english!
Zend_Validate.php is in vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages/fr/

Where is my error ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I used your code in my onBootstrap Module.php method of namespace Application.

Though it doesn't work where I was testing, searching the related topic here, at stack overflow.com, I found this code that uses 'default' and not **NAMESPACE** as the third parameter $textMode.

Then, when I changed my **NAMESPACE** constant by 'default', a path error of file happened.

I don't know how fix this and I didn't find how to do it yet. But, I think that you can use the same solution that I used, that is, putting the full path of resources' directory.

Example code (default): 
[Zend Framework 2 - Translate Standard Form Validation and Error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949240/zend-framework-2-translate-standard-form-validation-and-error-messages)

Method's doc here (addTranslationFile):
http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.2/classes/Zend.Mvc.I18n.Translator.html

Comment: Hi, I've just seen your answer. Since 2 months, I worked elsewhere! Your solution is working : thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Put in your **module.config.php**

```
'translator' => [
    'locale' => 'fr_FR',
    'translation_file_patterns' => [
        [
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ], [
            'type'     => 'phpArray',
            'base_dir' => './vendor/zendframework/zendframework/resources/languages',
            'pattern'  => '%.2s/Zend_Validate.php',
        ],
    ],
],
```